# launch singularity in a slurm script

Tags: slurm

I have singularity installed on /usr/local/bin and want to launch singularity from my slurm scirpt on my linux cluster but I keep getting this  error "error:/var/spool/slurm/d/job01485/slurm_script: line 21: singularity: command not found"

Am I setting my path correctly?

Here is the important parts of my slurm script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BATCH --mail-user=
##SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
##SBATCH --nodes=2    # comments allowed
##SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00
##SBATCH --mem=500M
#SBATCH --output=test4.out



export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
echo $PATH
# where are we running?
pwd
hostname
singularity exec s.simg  hostname

# which OS is this?
cat /etc/issue
singularity exec s.simg
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're root, /usr/local/bin should already be in your path since slurm will run the job as your user.

Most likely, singularity hasn't been installed on the compute nodes where slurm is allocating your job.

If you are building the cluster yourself, I'd recommend setting up the [module](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) system and a shared mount just for applications and module files.

This will allow you to have a central source to keep everything up to date.